# How to leave TODOs for yourself as part of Xcode4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, todo

The one thing i like about Eclipse is that it lets one leave annotations like `//TODO:`, which IDE highlights and draws your attention to.

Is there anything like this available for Xcode?

Ultimately, i'd like to mark things as to be completed without fear of forgetting to revisit this code later. Searching for this is fine, but i can't help but think there has got to be something better.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// FIXME: foo
// TODO: bar
```

Works the same.
In addition, these show up in the drop-down list of method names, so you can see and jump right to the areas that need more work.

Comment: No special highlighting though. Is there a way to get a consolidated list of all //TODOs? Additionally, when placed inside methods, these comments are not seen by method explorer

Comment: In the drop down, they are in bold so they stand out. Of course you can search for these tags (as you mentioned). I am not aware if there is a way to get a consolidated list, but there might be!